# org agenda: only show immediate subtask for task with dependencies

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Let's say I have a project with three subtasks:

```
* TODO project [1/3]
  :PROPERTIES:
  :ORDERED:  t
  :END:
** DONE subtask1
   CLOSED: [2020-04-05 Sun 15:12]
** TODO subtask2
** TODO subtask3
```

I have set the first item to DONE, and the progress entry shows [1/3] so it seems like org mode recognized the dependency. In the agenda todo view I now only want to see subtask2, because I cannot start working on subtask3 before it's done. However I now see both subtask2 and subtask3 in agenda todo. Is it possible to configure so that I only see subtask2 there?

Comment: See [TODO Dependencies](https://orgmode.org/manual/TODO-dependencies.html#TODO-dependencies) in the manual.

Answer (score 2):

Setting these variables made it work:

```
(setq org-agenda-dim-blocked-tasks 'invisible)
(setq org-enforce-todo-dependencies t)
```

Comment: This didn't _seem_ to work for me, until I ran `M-x org-mode-restart`.